# Error message says I didn't override abstract method, although I did

Tags: java, swing

My question is about an error message I don't understand. Well.. I do understand what it says, but not why it says so or how to fix it. I just started the learning chapter about Swing, and this is one of the examples in my course. I copy/pasted every word into Netbeans but for some reason, it doesn't work.

I have a class called MijnVenster (meaning "MyWindow"), where a JPanel is created with some JButtons with an ActionListener. In the class, there are 2 inner classes describing the performed action.

1. There's an error message next to both class headers,, saying:

> MijnVenster.HoofdLetterListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed (ActionEvent in ActionList)

2. The other error message next to both @Override statements says:

> method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Isn't that exactly what I did?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class MijnVenster extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final static String ZIN = "Hier staat een zin";
    private final JTextField textField = new JTextField(ZIN);

    public MijnVenster() {
        super("Letters");
        add(textField);
        JPanel panelSouth = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JButton buttonHoofdLetters = new JButton("Hoofdletters");
        panelSouth.add(buttonHoofdLetters);
        JButton buttonKleineLetters = new JButton("Kleine letters");
        panelSouth.add(buttonKleineLetters);
        add(panelSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        buttonHoofdLetters.addActionListener(new HoofdLetterListener());
        buttonKleineLetters.addActionListener(new KleineLettersListener());
    }
    // an inner class for upper case
    private class HoofdLetterListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            textField.setText(ZIN.toUpperCase());
        }
    }
    // an inner class for lower case
    private class KleineLettersListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            textField.setText(ZIN.toLowerCase());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you outer class is abstract your inner class has also to be abstract.

Comment: Check your imports. Is `ActionEvent` imported as `java.awt.event.ActionEvent`?

Comment: @MuratK. who says his class is Abstract?

Comment: I'm going with @talex on this. you are probably passing a different type of ActionEvent, which makes it an implementation of a (non-existing) overloaded method

Comment: The outer class is not abstract and my course didn't mention anything about any imports, but I clicked "Fix imports". I copied all of the code into the original post for more clarity.

Comment: You are using the wrong import for ActionEvent, use the one @talex metnioned in his comment, and your code 'll work

Comment: awesome, it worked indeed! Thanks :-)

Comment: Just a friendly advice, since you just start playin with Swing. Try to use lamdas for listeners, or at least, implement them in your class. Making a different class for each listener may lead to a messy and dirty code. :)